# Get facebook campaigns for specific user

Tags: facebook-ads-api

Good day!
I'm trying to get campaigns, which related to adAccounts where i was invited, via Facebook API, but i'm getting an error that only admin of this adAccount can use this method(https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_{ad_account_id}/campaigns). This is weird, because i can see some of the campaigns on my ad page in Facebook.
So the question is: how can I get the campaigns for user, which token was provided.
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand : what you need is to your app (website) access the ads campaigns of the other users

this is possible if they give your app (website) the permission of it.

the facebook api need 3 fields to work :

```
Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
```

the $app_id and the $app_secret must be the yours from : facebook for developer

the $access_token is what you need to access your ads or other users ads

so if you need to access other users ads you must ask them to give you the permission and to do it you need to follow the tutorial in [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/sdks)

you can now access any users campaigns and see it if they give you the permission